# Error when defining a query param type List<int> inline using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am not sure if this is a bug or not, but am getting an error and I am not seeing what the cause is. I have a method that takes an argument that takes a query param.

```
public static List<EmailNotification> GetEmailNotifications (EmailNotificationQuery query)
{
    using (HalDataContext hal = new HalDataContext())
    {
        IQueryable<EmailNotification> emailNotifications = hal.EmailNotifications;

        if (query.EmailNotificationID != null)
        {
            emailNotifications = emailNotifications.Where(en => en.EmailNotificationID == query.EmailNotificationID);
        }

        if (query.EmailNotificationIDs.Count > 0)
        {
            emailNotifications = emailNotifications.Where(en => en.EmailNotificationID.In(query.EmailNotificationIDs));
        }

        if (query.EmailNotificationTemplateID != null)
        {
            emailNotifications = emailNotifications.Where(en => en.EmailNotificationTemplateID == query.EmailNotificationTemplateID);
        }

        //this was causing error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        if (query.EmailNotificationTemplateIDs.Count > 0)
        {
            emailNotifications = emailNotifications.Where(en => en.EmailNotificationTemplateID.In(query.EmailNotificationTemplateIDs);
        }

        return emailNotifications.ToList();
    }
}
```

And the Query class

```
public class EmailNotificationQuery
{
    public EmailNotificationQuery ()
    {
        EmailNotificationIDs = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> EmailNotificationIDs { get; set; }
    public int? EmailNotificationID { get; set; }
    public int? EmailNotificationTemplateID { get; set; }
    public List<int> EmailNotificationTemplateIDs { get; set; }
}
```

When I would call the method like the following, LINQ would error out.

```
emailNotifications = EmailNotification.GetEmailNotifications(
  new EmailNotificationQuery() { EmailNotificationTemplateIDs = new List<int> 
      {(int)HalTypes.EmailNotificationType.EmployeeAddedToTask, 
       (int)HalTypes.EmailNotificationType.EmployeeRemovedFromTask} });
```

If I DID NOT define the list inline, then the query would work, but when it was defined inline, it would puke the following error:

> Method 'Boolean In[Int32](Int32,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' has no
>   supported translation to SQL.

Is this a LINQ bug, or am I missing somthing?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I've used queries like `emailNotifications = emailNotifications.Where(en => query.EmailNotificationTemplateIDs.Contains(en.EmailNotificationTemplateID);` with EF5/6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is giving you the information you need.

```
Method 'Boolean In[Int32](Int32, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

LINQ is trying to create a SQL statement to match the instructions you've provided, but is choking on the In method, which I'm assuming is an extension method you've defined on

```
Nullable<int>
```

Try instead:

```
emailNotifications = emailNotifications.Where(en => query.EmailNotificationTemplateIDs.Contains(en.EmailNotificationTemplateID));
```

EDIT: If you're not using it already, [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a great way to debug your LINQ queries. Not affiliated with it at all, just a happy user.

Comment: Nice. Thanks! I knew the error was stating it, but wasn't understanding why. Thanks again, and solved the problem.

Comment: Didn't realize it was an extension. Still little new to LINQ. This is why it fumbled, the extension was returning items.contains(o). So the naming convention of the extension through me off. Thanks again.